# How to filter results from Controller in View

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I need to display some elements inside my View and then filter them depending on user selection. I tried to compare variables from controller result with javascript variable but it seems it's not possible in this situation.

I have the following model:

```
create_table "appointments", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "doctor_id"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "start_date"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.datetime "end_date"
end
```

Inside my controller I have this to get all appointments:

```
@appointments = Appointment.all
```

Now inside my View I display all appointments like this:

```
events: 
    [
    <% @appointments.each do |appointment| %>
      {
        id     : "<%= appointment.id %>",
        title  : "Reserved",
        start  : "<%= appointment.start_date.in_time_zone.strftime '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S' %>",
        end    : "<%= appointment.end_date.in_time_zone.strftime '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S' %>",
        allDay : false
      },
    <% end %>
    ],
```

That works perfectly but I have an option that user can select a doctor and only appointments from that doctor should appear. How can I accomplish that? I tried to filter them like this but it's not working:

```
events: 
    [
    <% @appointments.each do |appointment| %>
    if <%= appointment.doctor_id %> == doctor_id{
      {
        id     : "<%= appointment.id %>",
        title  : "Reserved",
        start  : "<%= appointment.start_date.in_time_zone.strftime '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S' %>",
        end    : "<%= appointment.end_date.in_time_zone.strftime '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S' %>",
        allDay : false
      },
      }
    <% end %>
    ],
```

Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** To get the appointments for only one doctor using a select box, first send an ajax request when an option is selected in the select box:

```
$("select").change(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: 'selected=' + $("select option:selected").text(),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      if ($.trim(data) !== '') {
        // data should be the returned json of all the appointments for only the selected doctor. Do whatever you want with it.
      }
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      console.log(textStatus);
      console.log(errorThrown);
    },
    url: <insert post route here>
  })
});
```

This is what the controller action would look like:

```
def retrieve_doctor_id
  selected_doctor = Doctor.find(params[:selected])
  @appointments = selected_doctor.appointments.select([:id, :start_date, :end_date])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json render :partial => "your_controller/retrieve_doctor_id", :locals => {:appointments => @appointments}
  end      
end
```

File: app/views/your_controller/retrieve_doctor_id.json.erb:

```
events: 
[
<% appointments.each do |appointment| %>
  {
    id     : "<%= appointment.id %>",
    title  : "Reserved",
    start  : "<%= appointment.start_date.in_time_zone.strftime '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S' %>",
    end    : "<%= appointment.end_date.in_time_zone.strftime '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S' %>",
    allDay : false
  },
<% end %>
],
```

I haven't tested this, so tell me if there are any errors or problems with it.

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't work because doctor_id is a javascript variable which I create after user selects an option from drop down menu. I receive the following error: "undefined local variable or method `doctor_id'"

Comment: @ZdravkoVajudin I think the only way to compare the javascript variable and the ruby/rails variable would be to have an ajax post request occur after the select box is changed, which then goes to a controller that sends back to the javascript the appointment's `doctor_id`. I'll update my answer with what I'm talking about.

Comment: @ZdravkoVajudin I have updated my answer, hopefully it works better.

Comment: I think we are close. The only problem left is that @appointments don't contain data when events are filled. I receive the following error: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

Comment: When I try to print id in 'success' function, I can successfully print it like this: alert(data[0].id); So @appointments is set in controller but it's not set inside View. Hm..

Comment: @ZdravkoVajudin I have updated my answer rendering it as a partial instead of a file and passing the assignments as a local variable.

Comment: undefined local variable or method `appointments'. What do I need to put inside partial _show.json? I put inside my View after success: <%= render 'users/show.json' %>

Comment: @ZdravkoVajudin Sorry about that, I forgot to change the partial path. You should just be able to put the render in the controller and have the data returned after success be the json for the appointments.

Comment: Now I'm receiving: "ActionView::MissingTemplate Missing partial" because retrieve_doctor_id is not a partial. The problem is that that action is not called 'retrieve_doctor_id'. It's called 'home' and I can't access anything outside 'home' action. When I put as a test inside my 'home' action this: @appointments = Appointment.where(doctor_id: '3') I receive all appointments of that doctor. When I'm triggering another action from View, like 'retrieve_doctor_id' and set there something I can't get it back to my 'home' View.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```
events: 
    [
    <% @appointments.select { |a| a.doctor_id == @doctor_id }.each do |appointment| %>
      {
        id     : "<%= appointment.id %>",
        title  : "Reserved",
        start  : "<%= appointment.start_date.in_time_zone.strftime '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S' %>",
        end    : "<%= appointment.end_date.in_time_zone.strftime '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S' %>",
        allDay : false
      },
    <% end %>
    ],
```

assuming that `@doctor_id` is the id of the doctor you want to filter by. However, I must comment that this approach is really messy. You should really be using a json builder such as [rabl](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl).

Comment: Thank you but the problem is that doctor_id is created when user selects an option from drop down menu so it's a javascript variable which I can't compare like that.